# Is there a way to have GestureRecognizer Commands work within a Xamarin Forms button?

Tags: xamarin.forms, uigesturerecognizer

I'm looking to get Swipe and Tap events both working on a button in Xamarin Forms, using the Command pattern.

However, I fail at the first fence, since if I put a Tap Command inside a GestureRecognizer (ButtonA below) then the event doesn't register.

If I put the Command directly inside the button (ButtonB below) then it does register.

Others have reported problems with GestureRecognizers in Buttons, so i tried embedding the GestureRecognizer in a StackLayout, but that doesn't register either.

```
        <Button x:Name="buttonA" Grid.Row="1" Text="Button A" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" >
            <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
                <ClickGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
            </Button.GestureRecognizers>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="buttonB" Grid.Row="2" Text="Button B" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                Command="{Binding OnCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" >
        </Button>
        <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" >
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding OnCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Button x:Name="buttonC" Text="Button C" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: Different from other control like label , button is a click-able element .It will have conflict between ClickGestureRecognizer  and Click Event (command) . This is a known issue , you could check https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/4341 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucas' comment put me on the right track.
Here's a summary of behaviors as I understand them:

(*) Putting GestureRecognizers of any kind - including a ClickGestureRecognizer - into a Button conflicts and wont work (buttonA below)

() Putting the Command directly into the Button does work (buttonB below)

() Putting GestureRecognizers into an element such as a Grid or a StackLayout that **contains** a Button conflicts and wont work (LayoutA + buttonC below)

() Removing the Button from the Grid or StackLayout fixes the problem (LayoutB below)

```
        <Button x:Name="buttonA" Grid.Row="1" Text="Button A" BackgroundColor="LightGreen" >
            <Button.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
                <ClickGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
            </Button.GestureRecognizers>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="buttonB" Grid.Row="2" Text="Button B" BackgroundColor="LightBlue"
                Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" >
        </Button>
        <StackLayout x:Name="LayoutA" Grid.Row="3" >
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
            <Button x:Name="buttonC" Text="Button C" BackgroundColor="Orange" />
        </StackLayout>
        <StackLayout x:Name="LayoutB" Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="White" >
            <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding TapCommand}" CommandParameter="Button" />
                <SwipeGestureRecognizer Direction="Left" Command="{Binding SwipeCommand}" CommandParameter="leftSwipe" />
            </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        </StackLayout>
```

Comment: You could accept your answer , or I can post my answer with more details then you could accept it :)